Hyper V Internal switch: how to set subnet and gateway
I have a HyperV switch. When I run hnsdiag list networks, the following is returned:
03D8864D-7F72-412C-AC60-CC3056A1AE11
Name: staticip
Type: Internal
Subnet Address: 172.31.224.0/20
Gateway: 172.31.224.1
How can I change the Subnet Address and Gateway?
I found "Install-Module -Name HNS" so I have the "Get-Hns" and "Remove-Hns" functions. I was expecting "Set-Hns" functions.
I tried to connect network adapters to the virtual switch with IP addresses in the range that I expected (not the addresses returned by hnsdiag).
I looked in the registry. I found the virtual switch and its subnet and gateway in binary data. I was expecting to find a string registry value to modify.

What are you trying to accomplish?

just add a other switch and set it as external

I want to define the address range of my virutal machines. I don't want an external network, my virtual machine has two network cards, one external with an IP address provided by DHCP and an internal network where I manage the IP address range.

Unfortunately, the Set-Hns cmdlet is not available, but you can use the New-HnsNetwork cmdlet to create a new network with the desired settings and then just remove the old one.
Here's how you can do it, as simple as I can put it:
Get the current network object:
$network = Get-HnsNetwork -Name "staticip"

Create a new network with the desired settings:
$newNetwork = New-HnsNetwork -Name "staticip" -Type Internal -SubnetAddress "172.31.240.0/20" -Gateway "172.31.240.1"

Replace the subnet address and gateway with your desired values.
Remove the old network:
$network | Remove-HnsNetwork -Force

This will remove the old network with the original settings.
Verify the changes:
hnsdiag list networks

This should now display the updated subnet address and gateway for the "staticip" network.
Note: Be cautious when modifying network settings, as it may affect existing virtual machines and connections, and  remember to update any dependent virtual machines or network adapters accordingly.

Ok I can create a "HNS Network" the command below worked :
$newNetwork = New-HnsNetwork -Name "staticip" -Type Internal  -AddressPrefix "192.168.10.0/24"  -Gateway "192.168.10.254"
But how do I link either a HyperV Switch or a virtual machine to this network ? I don't see the HNS Network on the Graphial User Interface of HyperV and I don't see how to select the network with the "New-VMSwitch" command.
